# Circular reference of modules

Tags: java, module, java-platform-module-system

I am starting to grasp jigsaw slowly (I needed to completly re-setup my whole project from scratch to even get it to compile anything).

Now, I have multiple modules, multiple module-info.java files and multiple poms. The project was created by IntelliJ and the structure looks ok to me.

Now, the "util" module requires the "process" module in the module-info.java and vice-versa. Each one of them needs to instantiate classes from the other.

client

-- process

---- requires util

-- util

---- requires process

...

Now, when I try to compile that, it says:

`Error:java: Cannot compile a module cycle with multiple module-info.java files: util, process, gui`

I kind of see what it is complaining about, but I cannot see a way out of it. Do I need to use "opens" on one of the modules? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have something in `util` which references anything other than internal classes. Move this "util class" out of the `util` and directly into `process` module

Comment: I have spent all last night in creating modules and splitting the whole project up because there were conflicting dependencies that would make compilation impossible (hundreds of split packages)... And now I am re-moving everything into the util package so that it can see the classes it needs. I am not far away from abandoning the whole thing. Hours and hours of waste.

Comment: When you have two modules with such a cyclic dependency, the typical solutions are A) merge them into one module (as their tasks are not that decoupled) or B) split them into three modules, moving commonly used code into the new module which can be used by the other two, or C) use abstraction. E.g. module A provides an interface, B provides an implementation and registers a factory for instances of the implementation class to A, so B requires A but A still can create instances of a class provided by B.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger Abstraction way is the good one